# Query Mongo for empty object

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to query a mongo collection where a field is not an empty object.  `db.collection.find({Status: {$ne: {}}})` works from javascript, my question is how to translate the empty object representation to go/go's driver?

`filter := bson.M{"Status": bson.M{"$ne": {}}}` generates a `composite literal type interface{}` syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer (which became obvious as I was writing this question) is to add `bson.M` to my empty object:

```
filter := bson.M{"Status": bson.M{"$ne": bson.M{}}}
```